# adding a zero at first element in a numpy array or a way to create an array keeping the first position as zero

Tags: arrays, numpy

I got this function to looking for some specific characters in a string and if it is found it add  a value at that position in the array, ex:

```
def skew_array(text):
    import numpy as np
    skew = np.zeros(len(text))
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if text[i] == 'G':
            skew[i] += 1
        elif text[i] == 'C':
            skew[i] -= 1
        else:
            skew[i] = 0
    return np.insert(skew, 0, 0)

>> skew_array('gacaattagcaa'.upper())
array([ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.])
```

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it (inserting at the end) or if there are a way just to keep the first position as zero when creating the array.

I appreciate any tip!
Thank you by your time.

PS - I was using a list, but it is very bad for memory in bigger strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that functions that change the flat size of arrays are pretty slow, so i'd create skew larger from the start. and you can use a dict to avoid an elif soup

```
import numpy as np
def skew_array(text, dict_):
    skew = np.zeros(len(text)+1)
    for i, char in enumerate(text, start=1):
        skew[i] = dict_.get(char, 0)
    return skew

skew_dict={"G":1, "C":-1}
code='gacaattagcaa'.upper()
print(skew_array(code, skew_dict))
```

Comment: Since you need both the index and the value at said index, it would be better to loop with `for i, char in enumerate(text, start=1)`. The dict could also contain only the keys for G and C and then fetch the value with `dict.get(key, 0)`.

Comment: i always forgot about that start argument, thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the dict suggestion is a preference. I just think leaving out any zero keys makes it less cumbersome to write and it's more apparent what has non-zero values. But for only 4 keys, initialising all 4 is also fine.

Comment: that's part of the things i always forget though they are very handy when we need them. so i'm really ok with that

Comment: That is very nice! Thanks